# React and typescript dynamic grid resize

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make dynamic grid resize by change lgEditorSize value using onClick action for react and typescript code.

Declare initial lgEditorSize value

```
const x: any = {};
x.lgEditorSize=6;
```

Change lgEditorSize value

```
<Box display='flex' justifyContent='right'>
      <span>Show or hide the sidebar using</span>
      <Button onClick={() => {x.lgEditorSize=12;}}> <ArrowBackIosIcon/> </Button>
      <Button onClick={() => {x.lgEditorSize=6;}}> <ArrowForwardIosIcon/> </Button>  
      <span>Button</span> 
</Box>


<GridContainer>
            <Grid item lg={x.lgEditorSize}>
                Contents
            </Grid>
<GridContainer>
```

The value is changed but grid not resized,Any thoughts to resize Grid using Button action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the variable, but the Component isn't re-rendering because it doesn't know it needs to. To achieve re-renders, you need to use state, because React is smart enough to know that when a state changes, all the components using that state should re-render.

You should place the `lgEditorSize` into a state and use the state variable. It would look something like this.

```
const [lgEditorSize, setLgEditorSize] = useState<GridSize>(6); 

<Box display='flex' justifyContent='right'>
      <span>Show or hide the sidebar using</span>
      <Button onClick={() => setLgEditorSize(12)}> <ArrowBackIosIcon/> </Button>
      <Button onClick={() => setLgEditorSize(6)}> <ArrowForwardIosIcon/> </Button>  
      <span>Button</span> 
</Box>


<GridContainer>
            <Grid item lg={lgEditorSize}>
                Contents
            </Grid>
<GridContainer>
```

You can read more about `state` and the React component lifecycle here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: I tried this solution before But I got error in this line <Grid item  lg={lgEditorSize}>
     Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean | GridSize | undefined'.

Comment: @Ali-Alrabi I've edited my answer to add the type to the `useState`, you will need to import the `GridSize` type from MaterialUI or whatever component library you are using.